# How do I update a mailgun route in google app scripts

Tags: python, google-apps-script, mailgun

I have a python script that updates mailgun routes passing multiple actions parameters to the existing route. This works fine, but I'm having trouble recreating it in a Google App Script. Everything works when I pass a single action parameter, but I get errors when attempting to pass more than one.

Here is a working curl for the route update as well (api key and route 
ID redacted):

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'-H 'Content-Length: 63' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'User-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0' -d 'action=forward%28%22testing%40gmail.com%22%29&action=stop%28%29' https://api.mailgun.net/v3/routes/{routeID}
```

Here is what I have in my google app script currently. This works if I replace the "multi" variable with "address" or "stp".

```
      var address = "forward" + "(" + '"' + fwd + '"' + ")";
      var stp = "stop()";
      var multi = [address, stp]
      var params = {
        action: multi,
      }
      var base = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/routes/";  
      var url = base + routeID

      var options = {
        "method": "put",
        "payload": params,
        "headers": {
          Authorization: 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode("api:" + MAILGUN_KEY)
        }
      };
```

I'm not sure why this works perfectly in Python and curl, but not in the google script.

Comment: Here is the route api doc for mg: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-routes.html#actions

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
      var actions = "action=forward" + "(" + '"' + addr + '"' + ")" + "&action=stop()";
      var base = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/routes/";  
      var url = base + routeID

      var options = {
        "method": "put",
        "payload": actions,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "headers": {
          Authorization: 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode("api:" + MAILGUN_KEY)
        }
      };
```